# Azure Data Factory self-hosted Integration Runtime auto update issues

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have some problem with self-hosted `Integration Runtime` in `Azure Data Factory V2`.
I have a few VMs running 4.X.X IR software. Some of them had `auto update` enabled in DFv2
There was an update from 4.X.X to 5.X. After this, IR is unavailable from DFv2.
Looks like the IR services running on the VMs are pointing to a wrong execute path - using still 4.0. I can fix it manually with `sc config` or reinstall IR, but after reboot it doesn't work again.
Is that a bug? Can I somehow fix it without removing the VMs?

Update:

What I did - I went to Data Factory V2 Integration Runtimes and picked my self-hosted IR, went to `Auto update`  and enabled it. My Virtual Machine hosting this IR was running an older IR software (4.X.X). There was an update to 5.X.X. Everything was working fine until I rebooted the VM. After this from Data Factory V2 Integration Runtimes I was seeing an error saying that my self-hosted IR is unavailable. I logged into the hosting VM and it turned out that IR software cannot start its service `dmgsvc.exe`. When you go to `services.msc` and check the `Integration Runtime` service pointing to  the `dmgsvc.exe`, the path will be incorrect. What was wrong there? It was a catalog 4.0 instead of 5.0. IR software cannot start up correctly because of that and the error is `Error 2: System cannot find the file specified`. So what I did? I manually fixed it and it was working. But after the first reboot of the VM it was again pointing to the 4.0 catalog. I reinstalled the software and the effect was the same.

Comment: It's still an issue. As a workaround I added a custom script to run each time VM starts using `sc config` to change the path for the service.

Answer (score 0):

For the upgrade to version 5.x of the Azure Data Factory self-hosted integration runtime, we require .NET Framework Runtime 4.7.2 or later. On the download page, you'll find download links for the latest 4.x version and the latest two 5.x versions.

- If automatic update is on and you've already upgraded your .NET
  Framework Runtime to 4.7.2 or later, the self-hosted integration
  runtime will be automatically upgraded to the latest 5.x version.
- If automatic update is on and you haven't upgraded your .NET
  Framework Runtime to 4.7.2 or later, the self-hosted integration
  runtime won't be automatically upgraded to the latest 5.x version.
  The self-hosted integration runtime will stay in the current 4.x
  version. You can see a warning for a .NET Framework Runtime upgrade
  in the portal and the self-hosted integration runtime client.

Refer: [Troubleshoot self-hosted integration runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide#self-hosted-integration-runtime-version-5x)

Comment: Hi, the first case is what I have. .NET Framework Runtime 4.7.2 is already installed and automatic update is on. However, the problem persists

Comment: Can you share any specific error message you see or elaborate the the steps you performed.